# JPA named queries

Tags: jpa

I have a java class that implements serializable and the class begins with :

```
@NamedQueries( {
@NamedQuery(....)
@NamedQuery(....)
...
..})
```

My question is at what stage these queries are going to be executed because i see no direct call to these queries by their name
Project is using JPA. I think IBM implementation of JPA...surely not hibernate.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each named query has a name and the query is executed by invoking [EntityManager.createnamedQuery()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNamedQuery%28java.lang.String%29).

If the name of the query is based on a constant, you can search the usages of the constant in your project or if it's just a string, you can a text search in your project.

If you don't find any usages, there's a chance that those queries are not used at all, unless there's another framework that is invoking them (by doing something like convention over configuration).